# What about a questionnaire that is perfectly valid contentwise?

Tags: discussion, questions, hyperlinks

as an electrical engineering & computing science project we are intending to create a cheap iKVM (KVM over IP) box.

Every admin benefits from iKVM, so we would ask them to fill this questionnaire:
http://goo.gl/0PtzJ

Would that be appropriate?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to get away with posting on sysadmin mail lists, like lopsa/sage.  You might try contacting some of the more popular sysadmin bloggers, and see if they could link to you.

Comment: Whatever made you think this could be even remotely on topic for a Q&A site such as SF? On a personal note, just making broad and unjustified statements like "Every admin benefits from iKVM" pisses me off.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is not valid "content-wise". This is not a question, it is a request for participation. As such, it is entirely off-topic.

You can try your hand at posting it in chat, but we generally don't take kindly to people that post in, spam a link and leave. If you want to be an active member of the chat community it might be more well received. You are also more than welcome to put a link to the survey in your user profile, but including it in answers or as a stand-alone question is inappropriate.

Comment: As an aside, I'm glad that you found meta and asked if it was appropriate, many new users don't bother. You should check out the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq) and get a better feel for the Question and Answer format of SF compared to traditional forums. It's not enough to have the content be on-topic. It's weird for many new users to adjust to, but ultimately it keeps the content streamlined and relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Not on the main site, no - ServerFault is a place for Questions (pertaining to system administration, usually problems that someone encountered) that can be Answered ("Do X to fix it" or "Your design is wrong, consider these additional points and examples to come up with a new one").

Surveys and questionnaires don't lend themselves to that model.

---

All that said, having it appear on Meta means you'll probably get a few answers/views :)